# Reading Raw RGB video file in C++

Tags: c++, video, rgb

I am doing my assignment to read a .rgb video file and display it in the window. I have only known how to read and display an image in C++. What should I do when reading the video and display it frame by frame. I don't want to use third party libraries, just pure C++ and windows programming.
My idea is: firstly load the whole video file into the program using fopen and allocate the buffer for it. Then just like display an image, I wanna treat the whole video as an array of frames, so after rendering the first frame, I will go to the next frame. In addition, how to keep the video display at a constant fps? If you have any learning resources or coding pieces, it would be very helpful!
Thanks

Comment: Your question is tagged C++ so use C++ IO streams ([`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream)) for reading data from the file and [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to store the data. Give it a try and when you get stuck come back and ask a question when you run into a specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't mentioned platform you are using.
But this snippet will help you to read file frame by frame.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

        FILE * fp = NULL;
        int size = 800 * 600 * 2;
        unsigned char * rawData = NULL;
        fp = fopen("raw.rgb", "r+b");

        rawData = (unsigned char *)malloc(size);

        if (NULL == rawData)
                return -1;

        if (fp)
        {
                while(!feof(fp))
                {
                        fread(rawData, size, 1, fp);
                        // GOT FRAME
                }

                fclose(fp);
                fp  = NULL;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this without using any third-party library will be a lot of lot of works!

You may use the OpenCV library to do the work.  Check http://opencv.org/

Comment: Hi, our teacher asked us do not use the third party library:(

Comment: Anyway here is an example with OpenCV. https://gist.github.com/nipuntalukdar/c46686349e491730e5d7